# Map Options on flutter_google_maps plugin not Applying

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to add the compass and my location features of google map in the updated google_maps_flutter plugin but the options are being ignored and I get a map with no compass or locations buttons.

```
child: SizedBox(
          width: 500.0,
          height: 500.0,
          child: GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            compassEnabled: true,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              bearing: 270.0,
              target: LatLng(-12.34524, 21.08776),
              tilt: 30.0,
              zoom: 17.0,
            ),

          ),

        ),
```

I have the _onMapCreated function at the bottom of my page.

```
 void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
setState(() { mapController = controller; });
```

}

Does anyone know how to make these options work? I tried:

```
onMapCreated: _onMapCreated, 
options: GoogleMapOptions(
  myLocationEnabled:true,
  compassEnabled:true,
)
```

Android Studio just claimed that options and GoogleMapOptions are not valid.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have fill an issue 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37588

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work.
1st we need to give camera position then compass

child: SizedBox(

```
      width: 500.0,
      height: 500.0,
      child: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          bearing: 270.0,
          target: LatLng(-12.34524, 21.08776),
          tilt: 30.0,
          zoom: 17.0,
        ),
        compassEnabled: true,

      ),

    ),
```